# CakePHP 2.2.0 AjaxHelper Error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

> Strict (2048): Declaration of AjaxHelper::afterRender() should be compatible with Helper::afterRender($viewFile) [APP/View/Helper/AjaxHelper.php, line 1398]

I'm getting this error on my http://code-explore.com site. It's build on CakePHP & there was no problem. But after changing php.ini file by the server administrator I'm getting this problem.

It seems to me it may be caused for changing PHP version.

Any idea about why this occurs & how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: I will suggest you to try updating your helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you didn't upgrade cakephp/php ? Cause that looks like an incompatible method call, where you don't use a parameter where the (new) afterRender expects a $viewFile parameter.

If you could provide the changes that have been made in the php's ini file that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Maik. I requested my server administrator to change allow_url_fopen = On, but it seems he changed my PHP version. Hope, it will be perfect after get back to previous version.

Comment: Cool, glad to be of any use. The problem will resolve itself after changing back to an older php version cause that will not show that strict warning anymore. Nevertheless it is still a strict warning that you should fix